# How to make custom Alfresco AMP action fail?

Tags: java, action, alfresco, alfresco-module-package

I have developed a custom AMP action for Alfresco repo. I want Alfresco to understand that the action is failed if some condition is not satisfied and as a result show the failure message in pop-up.

I have written the followings in `executeImpl` method but the action does not fail if condition is not satisfied.

```
@Override
protected void executeImpl(Action action, NodeRef actionedUponNodeRef) {
    if (condition) {
    // Do something
    } else {
           ((ActionImpl) action).setExecutionEndDate(new Date());
           ((ActionImpl) action).setExecutionStatus(ActionStatus.Failed);
           ((ActionImpl) action).setExecutionFailureMessage("Action is failed");
           throw new RuntimeException("Action is failed");                        
           }
    }
```

Alfresco considers that the action is executed successfully. Yes, I have defined failure and success messages in `share-config-custom.xml`. Is there any way to manage the action in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried throwing `RuntimeException`, `ActionServiceException` but I don't know why throwing a `WebScriptException` works. Leaving the answer here if someone is looking for it:

```
@Override
protected void executeImpl(Action action, NodeRef actionedUponNodeRef) {
    if (condition) {
    // Do something
    } else {
           throw new WebScriptException("Action is failed");                        
           }
    }
```

Comment: WebScriptException works as a "brute force" solution as this type of exception is handled specially by the ReST API. It will however not be handled any differently than a regular RuntimeException by any other, non-ReST API uses of the action.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't (need to) set the properties of the ActionImpl class yourself - these are implementation details left to the ActionService to deal with.

Also, you should not throw a basic RuntimeException. In many cases, Alfresco will not process a basic RuntimeException in any way and simply propagate it up the call chain. It then depends on the HTTP / web script API that you is called if that actually triggers a "failure" message to Share.

The appropriate exception to throw is an ActionServiceException (which is a sub-class of RuntimeException).

For an error message to be displayed in Share, you'll also need to configure your documentlibrary action (which I assume you are using) to either include a "failureMessage" parameter (for a static message where you can use an I18n message key) or a "failure" parameter (for a dynamic handling where you must provide a callback function inside the XML configuration).

Comment: Each action that uses a pre-defined JavaScript function in Share can define / configure any of its parameters. For a set of available parameters it is advisable to look into the [action.js](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/share/src/main/webapp/components/documentlibrary/actions.js#L1396) file and JSDoc comments. Via the "failure" parameter you can specify the name of a function that should be called when an error occurs. In that function you could then inspect the error (ReST response) and react. The function would need to have been added to the Alfresco.doclib.Actions.prototype.